# are there any simple/example event-driven webservers in C?

Tags: c, events, event-driven, event-loop, evented-io

There are many example thread based web servers online, but I haven't really seen anything that gives a good example of an event-loop based one (without being very complex, e.g. lighttp and nginx).

Are there any? If not, what should I read/look at to help me learn how to make a server of this sort? (This includes asynchronous IO in C, etc.)

I already understand the basics of how event-loop based programming works, especially in higher level languages like Python, but I need to be able to implement one in C.

Comment: Look at thttpd, and also at GNU libmicrohttpd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is one](http://tupleserver.googlecode.com/svn-history/r7/trunk/tupleserver.c) which is part of [TupleServer](http://code.google.com/p/tupleserver/) source that uses [libevent](http://monkey.org/~provos/libevent/).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how full featured your server needs to be, but [here's](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/systems/library/es-nweb/index.html) a small C based web server that could be used as a starting point.  It forks a child process for each connection, so it's easy to understand, but not the most efficient.

Answer (score 0):

In short, simple : libevent.org and example : http://www.wangafu.net/~nickm/libevent-book/ .
As long as you get your hand in libevent, it's API working with http which is evhttp is not really robust, there is an alternative at https://github.com/ellzey/libevhtp . And of course libmicrohttpd works just fine.